# Accidentally discarded changes on wrong file, can I get back my changes?

Tags: git

I ran `git status` and got something like this:

[image: git status]

I then ran `git restore /path/to/modified/file` on the **wrong file**. So in effect, I discarded my changes to that file.

Is there a way I can get back my changes? My IDE was not helpful, so that's a no go.

I also hadn't done `git add .` or anything like that. Just `git status` followed by the `git restore` command.

Comment: I think there is no way to get it back unless rewrite your changes

Comment: If you had commited your work, and dropped a commit, you could have used `git reflog` to restore that commit .. but here, I'm afraid there is no other solution than rewrite your changes

Comment: if you using vscode https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_66.md#local-history